# Чтение данных из файла и работа с ними

Tags: java, io

**Задача :**

Есть файл.
Количество строк неизвестно.Каждая строка файла,представляет собой запись вида :

```
Покупатель Товар Количество
```

Нужно создать массив со всеми покупателями.

Для каждого покупателя подсчитать количество приобретенных им единиц каждого вида товаров.

Список вывести в алфавитном порядке фамилий покупателей.

**Входные данные из файла :**

```
Иванов газета 10
Петров ручка 5
Николаев тетрадь 3
Иванов ручка 2
Николаев ручка 1
Петров тетрадь 2
Николаев газета 1
```

**Выводимые данные на экран :**

```
Иванов : газета - 10 шт ; ручка - 5 шт ;
Николаев : газета - 1 шт ; ручка - 1 шт ; тетрадь - 3 шт;
Петров : ручка - 5 шт ; тетрадь - 2 шт;
```

**Мой код :**

```
package semnadcat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Марат
 */

public class Semnadcat2 {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\SomeDir\\notes3.txt")){
            int c;
            while((c=reader.read())!=-1){
                System.out.print((char)c);
            } 
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }   
 System.out.println(" ");
 } 
}
```

**Мои ошибки:**

Не понимаю каким образом можно сохранять в массив данные файла.
Удается только посимвольно вытащить информацию на экран.

Comment: Если хотите научиться программировать, читайте книжки по Java (и не только по Java). Без этого вряд ли что-то путное получится (и ответы на StackOverflow мало помогут), а время потратите.

Comment: @m.vokhm лично мне помогают. А книги - без практики ничего не дают.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В самом примитивном случае можно сделать так:

Создаете класс `Customer`:

```
public class Customer {
    private String mSurname;
    private String mProduct;
    private int mAmount;

    public Customer(String line) {
        String[] customer = line.split(" ");
        mSurname = customer[0];
        mProduct = customer[1];
        mAmount = Integer.parseInt(customer[2]);
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return mSurname;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return mProduct;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return mAmount;
    }
}
```

Создаете `ArrayList<Customer>` и заполняете его данными из файла:

```
ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Customers.txt"));
String currentLine;
while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    customers.add(new Customer(currentLine));
}
bufferedReader.close();
```

А дальше совсем просто.

**UPD:**

Вывод информации о покупателях на консоль:

- С помощью обычного цикла `for`:

  ```
  for (int i=0; i<customers.size(); i++) {
      Customer customer = customers.get(i);
      System.out.println(customer.getSurname() + " | " + customer.getProduct() + " | " + customer.getAmount());
  }
  ```
- С помощью цикла `for` в стиле `for each`:

  ```
  for (Customer customer : customers) {
      System.out.println(customer.getSurname() + " | " + customer.getProduct() + " | " + customer.getAmount());
  }
  ```
- С помощью Stream API (Java 8):

  ```
  customers.stream()
          .map(x -> x.getSurname() + " | " + x.getProduct() + " | " + x.getAmount())
          .forEach(System.out::println);
  ```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста,что делать дальше?Плохо понимаю дальнейшие действия.

Comment: я понял,что в ArrayList<Customter> происходит чтение файла и закидывается в конструктор класса Customer.Как сделать вывод и операции над полученными элементами?

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров, Дальше Вам нужно отсортировать полученный список по полю `mSurname` и вывести содержимое на консоль. Почитайте про коллекции в одной из классических книг (не сайтов!) по Java: Эккель, Шилдт или Хорстманн, там Вы сможете найти ответы на многие интересующие Вас вопросы. А от того, что я сейчас напишу Вам готовый код – толку будет мало.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!

Comment: не получается вывести на консоль это поле. Ну не понимаю я. Подскажите мне строку для вывода.Не получается.

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров, Добавил.

Comment: как сделать вывод типа : Иванов : газета - 10 шт ; ручка - 5 шт ;

Comment: с каждым покупателем

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров, Составьте список из уникальных фамилий. Отсортируйте исходный список по фамилиям. Для каждой уникальной фамилии из исходного списка выводите на экран товары для покупателя с заданной фамилией.

Comment: не работал со списками,пытаюсь в массив закинуть,но не получается. Всё совсем плохо ._.

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров, Можете преобразовать список в массив: `Customer[] customersArray = new Customer[customers.size()]; customers.toArray(customersArray);` и работать с массивом.